# How can I search for items with attributes matching a specified pattern via LDAP?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to search an LDAP server for all items with *exactly* the attributes specified.

The LDAP schema I'm dealing records user roles by:

1. creating a object type that may contain any of several attributes (the roles), and
2. setting the each role's value to be the same as its name

The attributes do not share a common base type, and the objectclass ("roleuser") contains other attributes that are not roles. Roles are distinguished by attribute names that end in "Role". (Yuck.)

Example. A user's object types would include object type roleuser, and might have the following attributes=value pairs:

```
cn=userX
  objectclass=roleuser,...
  managerrole=managerrole
  clerkrole=clerkrole

cn=userY
  objectclass=roleuser,...
  managerrole=managerrole

cn=userZ
  objectclass=roleuser,...
  clerkrole=clerkrole
```

I'm able to look up clerks, and managers, and manager clerks. But when I look up clerks (with `(&(clerkrole=*)(objectclass=roleuser))`), I get back users both with role clerk (userZ) and those with roles manager and clerk (userX).

I could specify `(&(clerkrole=*)(!managerrole=*)(objectclass=roleuser))`) to get clerks who are not managers. But that would require me to list (and negate) all possible other roles.

For various reasons, I don't want my application to have to know all possible roles, as these may change more quickly than my application will.

So. Is there a way to query the schema for all attributes that are in `roleuser` and are named `*role`, so that I could dynamically specify (and negate) all other roles?

Or is there a way to query for (clerkrole=*) and no other attribute named *role exists on that roleuser?

Comment: What LDAP server are you using? I'm asking because querying the schema could be a solution - but that depends on the type of server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider building your filter dynamically?  You could query the schema and retrieve all attributes ending in 'role', then iterate through them, discarding the one you want and adding (!___role=*) for each item and then add on the filter for the one you do want and query using that.